# how to get day of the selected date in fullcalender

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

how to get day of the selected date in fullcalender.I am working on fullcalender js and i want to get the day of the selected date ...i have tried using the day of the selected date using date.getDay();
but this isnt working...this is what i have done till now...

```
 dayClick: function(date,jsEvent, view) {
        var date=date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
         alert(date);
                                        }
```

this is working now i want to show the day-name of the selected date...how should i do that...kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> dayClick callback accepts date as the first parameter which holds [Moment](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) for
>   the clicked day. So to get the day name, use date.format('dddd');

```
dayClick: function(date){
  console.log(date.format('dddd')); //Gives the day here e.g: 'Tuesday'
}
```

Refer: [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You may not realize that date is not actually a Javascript `Date` object, it is a `moment.js` object. See help for moment.js.

For your particular case, this will be:

```
var dayOfMonth = date.date();
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

Answer (score 1):

i wrote my own piece of code to solve this issue...

```
    var date=date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    var day_no = moment(date).day();
    var days=['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
    var NameOfDays=days[day_no];
```